# React hook: How to call Modal component from another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a modal that I can reuse/call from multiple components. I want the modal to display in app.js but the button call is on another component.

Once I am able to implement one, I can but button on other components and call same modal instead of having to create the same modal for each component

```
<div className="App">
      <HeroSlider />
      <HowItWorks />
      <Modal />
      <Footer />
    </div>
```

The modal button is on this component(HeroSlider). Once its click it will call the modal component and display it in app.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from './Header'

function HeroSlider(props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const modalShow = () => setShow(true);
    const openIsAccount = () => {

    }
    return (

 <div className="jumbotron" id="jumbotron2" >
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="shoutBtn" onClick={modalShow}><span>Get Started</span>
</button>
 </div>
    );
}

export default HeroSlider;
```

Here is the Modal.js

```
const IsAccountOpen = (props) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return (
        <>
            <Modal show={props.show} onHide={handleClose} backdrop="static" keyboard={false}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    I will not close 
                 </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );

};

export default IsAccountOpen
```

Comment: I Agree with @Jkartunen. You'll probably want to extract the state of the modal to the app level and probably use context or redux as a global state container for that. Or at least do it if you'd like to avoid using tons of callbacks to change the state of the modal.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I followed everyone's suggestion about making the modal to be at the app level. I am still working on it to see how it behaves on the other components that will be calling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a function in the app.js to handle the click on the button, so the function will change the state show to true, and you will pass the state to your modal, like this:

App.js

```
[showState, setShowState] = useState(false)
buttonClickedHandler = () => {
   setShowState((showState) => showState = !showState )
}

<div className="App">
      <HeroSlider buttonClicked={buttonClickedHandler} />
      <HowItWorks />
      <Modal show={showState} buttonClicked={buttonClickedHandler} />
      <Footer />
</div>
```

HeroSlider.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from './Header'

function HeroSlider(props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const modalShow = () => setShow(true);
    const openIsAccount = () => {

    }
    return (

 <div className="jumbotron" id="jumbotron2" >
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="shoutBtn" onClick={props.buttonClicked}><span>Get Started</span>
</button>
 </div>
    );
}
```

export default HeroSlider;

IsAccountOpen.js

```
const IsAccountOpen = (props) => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return (
        <>
            <Modal show={props.show} onHide={props.buttonClicked} backdrop="static" keyboard={false}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    I will not close 
                 </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );

};

export default IsAccountOpen
```

I think the best solution is to use **redux**, because you will need to access and update the state from different components, you shouldn't use context API because the state changes frequently and you will hit the performance.

Comment: I used your code here but it can't close it with any of the two close buttons

Comment: Yes you need to pass the function buttonClicked to our modal, I edited my answer, check it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extract the state to App level, so that this can be shared to components. You can do this with useState, or using context & custom hooks if you want to make it very clean. But do it with useState on  first.

HeroSlider should receive modalShow function in it's props.
Modal.js should receive the show state as props.